# How to (automatically) remove or prevent popping up *Async Shell Command* in emacs?

Tags: emacs, ipc

As is asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668914/calling-one-editor-from-another-vi-emacs-mate). I could run vi or mate within emacs.

The problem is that after running **(async-shell-command "vi")**, I always have the *Async Shell Command" popped up as a window.

Can I prevent popping up this windows? Or, can I modify the emacs code to remove the window as soon as it pops up?

```
(defun runvi ()
  (interactive)
  (let (filename (file-truename buffer-file-name))
    (setq cmd (format "/Users/smcho/bin/mvim %s" (file-truename buffer-file-name)))
    (async-shell-command cmd)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work (assuming `cmd` is bound to the command you want, like you have above):

```
(save-window-excursion
   (async-shell-command cmd))
```

Comment: Curse Trey and his fast fingers; I was about to post exactly the same thing.